# CoreML Resnet50 Model has poor accuracy in physical device but works well in Xcode CoreML preview

Tags: ios, swift, machine-learning, arkit, coreml

I'm making object recognition app using Resnet50 model provided by apple. I'm integrating it with ARKit so that when ever the model detects an object I will display the identifier of the object using a SCNText node.Here is the model.
[Here is my model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruthE.jpg)
Here is my code

```
import CoreML
import Vision
import UIKit
import SceneKit
import ARKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!
    private var hitTestResult: ARHitTestResult?
    private var squeezeNet = Resnet50()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Set the view's delegate
        sceneView.delegate = self
        
        // Show statistics such as fps and timing information
        sceneView.showsStatistics = true
        
        // Create a new scene
        let scene = SCNScene()
        let boxGeometry = SCNBox(width: 0.2, height: 0.2, length: 0.2, chamferRadius: 0.0)
        boxGeometry.materials.first?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
        let boxNode = SCNNode(geometry: boxGeometry)
        boxNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: -0.5)
        boxNode.scale = SCNVector3(x: 0.2, y: 0.2, z: 0.2)
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(boxNode)
        // Set the scene to the view
        
        sceneView.scene = scene
        sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapped)))
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        
        // Create a session configuration
        let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()

        // Run the view's session
        sceneView.session.run(configuration)
    }
    
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        
        // Pause the view's session
        sceneView.session.pause()
    }
    
    
    
    @objc func tapped(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer){
        let location = self.sceneView.center
        guard let currentFrame = sceneView.session.currentFrame else{return }
        let hitResult = sceneView.hitTest(location, types: .featurePoint)
        if !hitResult.isEmpty{
            self.hitTestResult = hitResult.first
        }
        self.recognizeImageRequest(buffer: currentFrame.capturedImage)
        
    }
    
    
    func displayPrediction(text: String){
      
        if let hitTestResult{
            let node = createText(text: text)
            node.position = SCNVector3(x: hitTestResult.worldTransform.columns.3
                .x, y: hitTestResult.worldTransform.columns.3.y, z: hitTestResult.worldTransform.columns.3.z)
            self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
        }
        
      
    }
    
    private func createText(text: String) -> SCNNode {
        
        let parentNode = SCNNode()
        
        let sphere = SCNSphere(radius: 0.01)
        
        let sphereMaterial = SCNMaterial()
        sphereMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIColor.orange
        sphere.firstMaterial = sphereMaterial
        let sphereNode = SCNNode(geometry: sphere)
        
        let textGeometry = SCNText(string: text, extrusionDepth: 0)
        
        textGeometry.alignmentMode = CATextLayerAlignmentMode.center.rawValue
        textGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.orange
        textGeometry.firstMaterial?.specular.contents = UIColor.white
        textGeometry.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true
        
        var font = UIFont(name: "Futura", size: 0.10)
        textGeometry.font = font
        
        let textNode = SCNNode(geometry: textGeometry)
        textNode.scale = SCNVector3Make(0.2, 0.2, 0.2)
        
        parentNode.addChildNode(sphereNode)
        parentNode.addChildNode(textNode)
        textNode.position = SCNVector3(x: textNode.position.x, y: textNode.position.y - 0.15, z: textNode.position.z)
        return parentNode
    }
    


}


extension ViewController{
    func recognizeImageRequest(buffer: CVPixelBuffer){
        do{
            let visionModel = try VNCoreMLModel(for: squeezeNet.model)
            let request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: visionModel) { request , error  in
                if let error{
                    print(error)
                }
                if let result = request.results as? [VNClassificationObservation]{
                    print(result.first!.identifier)
                    print(result.first!.confidence)
                    self.displayPrediction(text: result.first!.identifier.components(separatedBy: ",").first!)
                }
            }
            
            request.imageCropAndScaleOption = .centerCrop
            
            let imageRequestHandeler = VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: buffer,orientation: .upMirrored,options: [:])
            DispatchQueue.global().async {
                do{
                   try imageRequestHandeler.perform([request])
                }
                catch{
                    print(error)
                }
                
            }
            
        }
        catch{
            print(error)
        }
       
    }
}
```

When I run my app in iPhone 7 with iOS 15.7.6 the accuracy is really bad. But when I test the model using Xcode CoreML model preview by dragging and dropping some images it works well. Am I doing something wrong in capturing the current image from the frame and passing it to the VNImageRequestHandler.

Comment: Have you tried running the model disconnected from scene kit just using test images? 
Try to narrow down the culprit